# Remove CSRF from payload in nextauthjs

Tags: next-auth

I am using [nextauthjs](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth) for authentication. It automatically adds a csrf token on every request. However, my backend does not support the csrf field and therefore the request keeps getting rejected. Is there a way to remove the automatically added csrf in nextauthjs? Here is part of my nextauthjs code

```
...
providers: [
        CredentialsProvider.default({
            name: 'Credentials',
            credentials: {
              username: { label: 'Email', type: 'email', placeholder: 'Email' },
              password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password', placeholder: 'Password' }
            },
            async authorize (credentials: any) {

                const fd = new URLSearchParams();

                fd.append('username', credentials.username);
                
                fd.append('password', credentials.password);
                
                const response = await fetch(
                    `${process.env.API}"login`,
                    {
                      method: "POST",
                      headers: {
                        'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                      },
                      body: fd.toString(),
                    }
                  );

                  const data = await response.json();
                  // Returning token to set in session
                  return {
                      token: data,
                    };
            }
        })
    ],
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `skipCSRFCheck` option to your config, something like this:

```js
const authConfig = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  skipCSRFCheck: true,
};
```

I would suggest you check this guide on NextAuthJS for more insights :  https://codelabsacademy.com/blog/passwordless-login-nextjs13-nextauth-prisma

Comment: It is only available on v5 and it has many breaking changes. Isn't there any other way to do it now with v4?